# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 2 in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was Sending data from CLient Site => server => Data Base.
But The error happens on the serverside's terminal.

```
syntaxError: Unexpected token 2 in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at createStrictSyntaxError (C:\Users\ANUPAM\Desktop\assigment\assigment-11\book-hut-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:160:10)
at parse (C:\Users\ANUPAM\Desktop\assigment\assigment-11\book-hut-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:1S)
at C:\Users\ANUPAM\Desktop\assigment\assigment-11\book-hut-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:128:18
at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:199:9)
at invokeCallback (C:\Users\ANUPAM\Desktop\assigment\assigment-11\book-hut-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:231:16)
at done (C:\Users\ANUPAM\Desktop\assigment\assigment-11\book-hut-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:220:7)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\ANUPAM\Desktop\assigment\assigment-11\book-hut-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:280:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
```

**This is my client-side Code.**

```js
fetch(putUrl, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newQuantity)
        })
```

**This is server-side code**

```
app.put('/update/:id', async (req, res) => {
            res.send('Go')
        })
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that can help us help you really. Assuming you're actually sending JSON to the server it's not doing anything with it. Where's the JSON.parse? In your code, or in the parser? Also, that PUT callback doesn't need to be `async`.

Comment: It looks like the body parser can't handle JSON data that contains only one number. IMO that's a bug in the body parser. According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON a string containing a number is valid JSON.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.